# csrf_token at get request - does that make sense?

Tags: django

As the title says:
does it make any sense to use csrf_token with get request e.g. for pagination variable

I do not think so but, did not find answer on the net, so that is why I am asking

Comment: If you protect your views manualy by decorator `@csrf_protect`, csrf_token makes sense, i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your application. If you use HTTP correctly, it has no sense. Simply put: Don't make data modification methods work on GET requests.

If you're making a simple web application, make every method that modifies something work with POST (create resources, delete, modify, even logout).

If you're doing some REST service, use the proper POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH methods.

Answer (score 0):

Django's CSRF middleware doesn't check the CSRF values on a `GET` request, so you can omit it without any danger (see also the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py#L109)).

Comment: thank you for reply and providing source code - very valuable point